# How do you pass serveral passwords in SCP using expect?

Tags: passwords, expect, scp

My purpose is control transferring files between two remote machines. If I could use `key-pair` it would be much easier but I can't choose the options but passing passwords.

Environments : `Local(Mac)`, `Remote_source(Linux)`, `Remote_target(Linux)`

Here it is my expect.sh. When I run it, `source@source's password:` pops up, then `target@target's password:` and nothing else. No files transferred, no stdout, no error message, just disconnected.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

spawn scp -3 scp://remote_source_user@host:port/home/source/test.txt scp://remote_target_user@host:port/home/target/

expect "remote_source_user@host's password:"
send "SOURCE_PASSWORD\r"

expect "remote_target_user@host's password:"
send "TARGET_PASSWORD\r"

expect eof
```

[image]

When I change the sequence the password (meaning send target password first rather than sending source password first.) it occurs error, so I guess it is working but I have got no idea what is going on internally.

I have tried `sshpass` but it is not working with several passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged it with `-v flag` and found out that Connection works perfectly but the problem is the directory.

```
# in debugging mode
Sink: scp: home/username/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

It seems not recognizing `/`home/username/test.txt at the beginning.
so the code should be like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

spawn scp -3 scp://remote_source_user@host:port/~/test.txt scp://remote_target_user@host:port/~/

expect "remote_source_user@host's password:"
send "SOURCE_PASSWORD\r"

expect "remote_target_user@host's password:"
send "TARGET_PASSWORD\r"

expect eof
```

Do not explicitly write your home directory `/home/username/` but use `/~/`.

```
# The Result
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f ~/test.txt
Sending file modes: C0000 00 test.txt
Sink: C0000 00 test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single / after the port number is interpreted as **relative to the user's home directory**.

If you want an **absolute path** use double // after the port number, like:

```
scp -3 scp://<username>@<host>:<port>//path/to/file
```

This applies for both source and destination.